# Scaling argument for the heat equation in a bounded domain

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We want to study the long time behavior of the heat equation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ in the domain $[0,1]$. Now consider the rescaling $u^{\epsilon} =  u(x/\epsilon, t/\epsilon^2)$. Then 
$u^\epsilon$ solves 
$$u^\epsilon_{t} - u^{\epsilon}_{xx} = 0 \quad \text{ in } [0,\epsilon].$$
When $\epsilon \to 0$ we are considering the long time asymptotic behavior of $u$. What happens to the domain? Why does it shrink to $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0):

To study the long term behavior of the solution, you will need to define the problem better, since $u$ is not determined by the equation alone. For example, the solution $t+\tfrac{1}{2}x^2$ tends to infinity, and its negative to minus infinity, while constant solutions never change, and solutions $e^{-c^2 t}\cos(c x)$ tend to zero. Boundary conditions are needed.

For your actual question, $u$ is defined on $[0,1]$, so in $u^\epsilon$ you have $x/\epsilon$ in $[0,1]$, therefore $x$ is in $[0,\epsilon]$.